# I have confusion in the answer given in book

Tags: matrices, permutations

The total number of skew symmetric matrices of the order $3\times 3$ that can be formed such that no two off-diagonal elements are equal and every element belongs to $\{-9,-8,-7,...,8,9\}$.

Total number of ways of filling the upper triangle should be equal to $18*16 *14=4032$. But the answer given is $672$.

Comment: @SarGe The OP *did* show their attempt.  The matrix being skew symmetric with distinct off-diagonal elements must be of the form $\begin{bmatrix}0&a&b\\-a&0&c\\-b&-c&0\end{bmatrix}$.  Choose the element $a$ in $18$ ways (*taken from $\{-9,-8,\dots,-2,-1,1,\dots,9\}$*) which removes both $a$ and $-a$ from the pool, choose the element $b$ in $16$ ways, and choose the element $c$ in $14$ ways.  Apply rule of product and conclude that there are $18\cdot 16\cdot 14=4032$ total such matrices.

Comment: @ OP, I see nothing wrong with your attempt and interpretation of the problem.  The answer of $672$ is difficult to explain.  If $672$ is an answer to a problem that relied purely on rule of product, we can note that $672 = 2\cdot 8\cdot 7\cdot 6$ which might give a clue as to what it is an answer to... but it doesn't appear related to the current problem.  My guess is that its an answer to a different problem and was mislabeled, misread, or similar.

Comment: "*Why is 'it' wrong?*"  If by "it" you mean the attempt in the body of the post, I don't think it is wrong.  I think it is correct.  If by "it" you mean the answer in your most recent comment, that is a different answer than what you gave before and is wrong... you only ensure the elements in the upper triangle were distinct and forgot about distinctness between elements in different triangles.  You might have accidentally picked $9$ and $-9$ in the upper triangle, but with $9$ picked in the upper triangle you'd have $-9$ in the lower triangle which we didn't want to happen, causing duplicate.

Comment: Yes, you're right. I realized that the moment after I commented.

Comment: if we divide 4032 by 3! , it will give 672 . Is there any any logic ?